# Run WebMatrix site in browser using VS Code

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-code

I have an existing WebMatrix-based website (ASP.NET WebPages framework) that I would like to edit and debug (or atleast "run") using Visual Studio Code.

I know that by editing the files in the .vscode folder, we can tell VS Code to run PHP?ASP.NET sites on localhost.

But I'm having a hard time figuring out what to actually write in the tasks file in VS Code so that my ASP.NET site will run in the browser?